# Kendo-Grid column field validation

Tags: validation, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-dataviz

I am working on populating kendo--grid with APIs data but on adding validation on one field is automatically working for every other fields too.

Here is schema inside kendo-dataSource :

```
schema: {
                   model: {
                       id : "id",
                       fields: {
                           id: { editable: false, type: 'number'},
                           name: { editable: true, type : "string" },
                           unique_url: { editable: true , type: 'string'},
                           image_url : { editable: true, type : "string" },
                           title: {type : "string", validation: {
                                                required: true,
                                                validateTitle: function (input) {
                                                    console.log("I am inside validation",input.val());
                                                    if (input.val().length > 5) {
                                                       input.attr("data-validateTitle-msg", "Max length exceeded 5 characters only");
                                                       return false;
                                                    }    

                                                    return true;
                                                }
                                            }
                                            },
                           body: { editable: true, type : "string",validation: { max: 90, required: true, message : "Maximum characters should be 90"} },
                           adaccount_id: { editable: false, type: 'number'}
                       }
                   }
                },
```

Here I have added validation for title field but its getting called for others fields too.
I am adding one snapshot of validation---
[image]

Please help me to find errors in it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't really any error in your code, but more like an error in Kendo Grid's validation design. Even though you specify the validation function only in the `title` field, it will run  the validation globally for any input field that you edit.

In `validateTitle` you need to filter which input you want the validating function to run on. Something like this:

```js
if (input.is("[name='title']") && input.val().length > 5) {
    input.attr("data-validateTitle-msg", "Max length exceeded 5 characters only");
    return false;
}
```

If you need a live working demo, you can always refer to Telerik's online demos that are editable, very handy for playing around with things. Here's the [**demo**](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-custom-validation) for custom validation where they similarly have to filter the input for the field name.

Comment: "an error in Kendo Grid's validation design" - you nailed it on the head there! The design is completely broken!

Answer (score 3):

[image]

you want simply required field validation means just add your view model property attributes

```
[Required(ErrorMessage ="CountryCode is Mandatory")]
        public virtual string CountryCode
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

We can easily set the maximum length using this code,It will not allow user to enter more characters than the specified one

```
  model: {
                    id: "CLASSID",
                    fields: {
                        CLASSID: { type: "number" },
                        CLSNAME: { type: "string" },
                        CLSFLAG: {
                            type: "string", validation: {
                                required: true,maxlength:"3"
                            }
                        },
                        CLSSTATUS: { type: "boolean" }
                    }
                }
```