# How to Access the ID from Kendo Model in KendoGrid / Custom validator editing?

Tags: validation, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using a Kendo Grid / Custom validator editing to **validate** the a Column in the grid,Actually  I'm trying the check the email already exists in the database or not ? to implement it I would like to get ID for the Row.

For example given in reference its products table, so in this case I would to get the ProductID inside the validation function ?

Reference:
http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-custom-validation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the id by retrieving the `uid` and then getting the data item from the dataSource via `dataSource.getByUid()`. Each row in the grid has a unique `uid` generated by the grid.

So for instance, referring to kendo's demo, the validation would now look like this:

```js
productnamevalidation: function (input) {
    //get row and uid
    var row = input.closest('tr')[0];
    var uid = $(row).attr('data-uid');

    //get data item and then its ProductID
    var dataitem = dataSource.getByUid(uid);
    console.log(dataitem);
    console.log(dataitem.ProductID);

    //continue doing validation
    if (input.is("[name='ProductName']") && input.val() != "") {
        input.attr("data-productnamevalidation-msg", "Product Name should start with capital letter");
        return /^[A-Z]/.test(input.val());
    }

    return true;
}
```

Here is their [demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/EnORu) with this code included, you can open the console to see that each data row is being printed out with all its model properties.

Comment: Not sure but the validation event is firing twice now. Any ideas?

Comment: @Binny Without seeing your code, I can't be sure, but I would say it is [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24678833/1860561). Basically every validation function runs globally for all columns, even though you only specify it for one column. So make sure your column validation logic is placed in the `if` statement that checks the input box. So for instance in my answer, move all the row ID checking into `if (input.is("[name='ProductName']") && input.val() != "")`

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29796437/kendo-ui-grid-custom-validation-is-firing-twice). Using ajax to validate the email?

Comment: FYI, this only works for inline grid editing.  If you're using the popup option then your row will be undefined.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the record's ID with this:

```
input[0].kendoBindingTarget.source.ID
```

For example:

```
emailUnique: function (input) {
    if (input.is("[name=Email]") && input.val() !== "") {
        input.attr("data-emailUnique-msg", "Email already exists");
        return isEmailUnique(input.val(), input[0].kendoBindingTarget.source.ID);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Bonus track, in case it's useful for someone:

```
function isEmailUnique(val, id) {
    var data = YourGridDataSource; // If you don't have it, you may need something like $("#YourGrid").data().kendoGrid.dataSource
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i].ID != id && data[i].Email == val)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```