# Kendo Ui grid Custom Validation is firing twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-grid

Kendo Ui grid Custom Validation is firing twice

My coding

```
schema: {
                    model: {
                        id: "StaffID",
                        fields: {
                            StaffName: { validation: { required: true }  },
                            RoleID: { field: "RoleID", type: "number", defaultValue: 2 },
                            Username: { validation: { required: true } },
                            Password: { validation: { required: true } },
                            Email: {
                                validation: {
                                    email: true, required: true,validateOnBlur: false,
                                    EmailValidation: function(input)
                                     **// This is fired twice**
                                   { 
                                        var valid = CheckEmailValidate(input,dataSource,dataItem);
                                        return valid;                                         
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Reference:
please Check
http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing

Comment: Is that when you're saving the row? If so, I believe that's expected. First the validation is called because the input is losing focus. Second, it's called because the row is being saved.

Comment: I thought the row is saved when u click the save changes button , but I can understand what you meant. Need to check and will get back to you. Thanks mate

Comment: if u r right, two types of saving are happening here. One an save event which saves the new value in grid and then when I click save changes button the value is saved in database. Now I wanted to disable blur or save event , I using ajax in my validation function. is it possible ?

Comment: You can't do ajax validation because the return statement will not wait for the ajax call to return

Comment: I did asynchronous ajax call

Comment: That's precisely why it won't work, because ajax is asynchronous. By the way, what action are you doing to cause the validation (e.g are you clicking save)?

Comment: not doing save, validation is triggered while doing onblur ? Ajax works fine , its been hit twice .

Comment: It hits the ajax, but that doesn't necessarily mean it works. My point is that `return valid` will always return before your ajax call is even done, and it won't care whether `CheckEmailValidate` returns true or false. Is the input box the same element for both validation calls?

Comment: Ok , return vaild reurns valye after ajax call only. Input value remains the same for both validations calls. I can see `EmailValidation` is triggered twice.

Comment: @gitsitgo any suggestions pls? I couldn't find any solutions yet ?